# Thunderbird can not download mail from Yahoo

Tags: email, thunderbird

When Thunderbird  went to get mail from Yahoo it would get and error “Connection to server … reset”.  When you tried again it would work.

I went to “https://help.yahoo.com/kb/new-mail-for-desktop/pop-access-settings-instructions-yahoo-mail-sln4724.html”   and found :

```
Incoming Mail (POP) Server
    • Server - pop.mail.yahoo.com
    • Port - 995
    • Requires SSL - Yes
```

My settings are:

```
 POP
pop.mail.yahoo.com      Port 995

    SSL/TLS
    Normal password
```

Before I had pop.att.yahoo.com as a server. I have tried both and no joy.
Now I get  a range of errors from  the server:
“Sending of password for user –me-- did not succeed.  … try again later.”
“Connection to server was reset ”

This would seam to point to a password error, but I can send email through the smtp server with out a problem.
Note: I have two passwords, one for the email (PW1) and one for the web yahoo.com(PW2).  I have tried both for the POP account and neither appear to work. Both are less than 30 chars.
I would reset the password for the email if I could figure out hot to do that. The Yahoo web site offers no help.
I have gone through all the similar questions that pop up with this tiltle and none seem to address the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yahoo Mail has made some obnoxious [changes to login method](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1301002) (and to terms of service) this past year. In particular, "You either have to use Option 2... OAuth2... OR use Option 3 where you... create a Yahoo **app-specific password** and in Thunderbird enter that as if it was your normal password." The password appears to be valid for only one application on one machine; and I've not had success creating a *second* for use on another PC.

Your choices, then, are to change login method, or to use another free email provider, such as GMail, [Mail.com](https://www.mail.com/) or [Outlook.com](https://outlook.live.com/owa/). Also, be aware that most free email providers provide little or *no* privacy, and state, for example, "[Provider] may disclose your personal information as it deems necessary..." *Caveat usor.*